# Dynamic name to structure variable in C

Tags: c, structure

I have an array 'y' with x no. of elements inside it (the number 'x' is given by user), I need to create an array of structures which has elements of exactly the same type as that in array 'y' i.e the array of structures would have 'x' elements.

Comment: Nice. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: If you have an array, you must have a length to safely work with it. Why can't you allocate an array of structures of the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have an "array" of some type, and the number of elements is decided by the user. I'm guessing you allocate it using `malloc` like this:

```
type_of_y *y = malloc(x * sizeof(type_of_y));
```

And now you want to create a similar "array" from a structure, with the same number of elements. Why can't you do it just like you do for `y`? I.e:

```
struct my_structure *new_array = malloc(x * sizeof(struct my_structure));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a structure such as this.  The type of the array is shown as `ArrayType`; you could write `int` or `double` or whatever else is appropriate for you.

```
typedef struct array
{
    size_t     num_elements;  // stores the 'x' value
    ArrayType *arr_elements;
} array;
```

You can then allocate an array of that type:

```
array *list = calloc(sizeof(array), number);
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    list[i].arr_elements = malloc(sizeof(*list[i].arr_elements) * array_size);
    list[i].num_elements = array_size;
}
```

You should error check the memory allocations:

```
if (list == 0)
   ...error...

   if (list[i].arr_elements == 0)
   {
       ...release already allocated space...
       ...error...
   }
```

Note that each array in the `list` of arrays (probably not the best choice of name) could have a different number of elements in it; the `num_elements` tells you how big that specific array is.

Note that the C99 *flexible array member* is not really a help here.  You cannot have an array of a structure containing a flexible array member, though you could have an array of pointers to them.

Comment: Using `calloc()` when you set the two parts of the struct right after is not optimised :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* new array */
MYSTRUCT *abc = (MYSTRUCT *)calloc(x, sizeof(MYSTRUCT));
/* copy contents of 'y' into new array */
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    abc[i] = y[i];
```